# How to draw a square using JNI and OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface

I am new in opengl as well as in jni. I know how to draw using java and opengl, but I want to draw the same using C.

Can anyone help me out?

I want to draw a square by calling draw( written in c) function from my java renderer class, where all the drawing will be done.

I have seen the san-angeles example, but it's complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the

> samples\san-angeles

folder of the NDK for a decent example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that but it's little complicated. Can you give a very basic example?